# when Html input range 'step' is not multiple of range's 'max' value

Tags: javascript, html, input, range

I have a situation where my range slider's step is not multiple of max value, so slider value goes only to 90, because next step would be greater than 100. the snippet:

```html
<input min=0 max=100 step=15 value=0 id='my-slider' type="range" oninput='onChange()'/>
<label id='label'>0</label>

<script type="text/javascript">
function onChange(){
  const val = document.getElementById('my-slider').value;
  document.getElementById('label').innerText = val;

}
</script>
```

my problem is that I want slider to reach maximal value (in this case 100), but I also want t retain the step value (15). desired behavior is something like that: 0 -> 15 -> 30 -> 45 -> 60 -> 75 -> 90 -> 100.
is there some simple way to achieve this or is it better to write custom slider with javascript?

Comment: Well you could set max=105, but only _display_ it as `100` in your label - and then of course take this into account wherever you actually work with / process the value later on. Other than that, I think you will probably have to come up with your own custom solution, because you simply want two things here that are contradictory to begin with.

Comment: Thanks man that's a good idea, I'm sorry I couldn't think of that myself :(

Answer (score 0):

Don't post the slider value directly and/or handle the value on the server

```js
function onChange() {
  let val = document.getElementById('my-slider').value;
  val = val >= 100 ? 100 : val;
  document.getElementById('label').innerText = val;
  document.getElementById('actualValue').value = val;
  console.log(document.getElementById('actualValue').value); // remove this when happy
}
onChange()
```

```html
<input type="hidden" id="actualValue" name="actualValue" value="" /><br/>
<input min=0 max=105 step=15 value=0 id='my-slider' type="range" oninput='onChange()' />
<label id='label'>0</label>
```