# Unable to reach input type range to max

Tags: html

I am trying to reach a max value of 105. But unable to do it. Is there possible to reach 105. Code below,

```
    <input type="range" min="0" step="10" max="105">
```

Comment: With step=10, what do you expect to happen?

Comment: I expecting that if it is possible to reach 105. but unable to reach. on the range, it is moving to 100 only.

Comment: You need step 5.

Comment: can we use any JS for the same? because I can not change steps. max value is dynamic. it can be a decimal value like 104.12

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just change the step size to 5:

```
<input type="range" min="0" step="5" max="105">
```

Otherwise you will not be able to reach 105 with steps of 10:

```
105 % 10 = 5
```

You will always get a rest of five, which is not reachable (in your sense).

Comment: Yes agree, But I can not change the steps. max value can be in decimal. 
can we use any JS for the same?

Comment: Have a look on that question, please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60000964/when-html-input-range-step-is-not-multiple-of-ranges-max-value It is not absolutely your case, but it might help to find a solution. Good luck! Tricky problem, that you've got.

Comment: Thanks, @Michael Czechowski, I can use this as a temporary solution.

Comment: This helped with a similar issue I had

Answer (score 0):

When you cannot change the step size and the starting point then may you can switch the range to 100% when it is at the most high point?
What you really want is impossible. Even manually setting the input will not work cause the input does not except 105 as valid value by definition at any state.
You can add a lower step rate and then correct it by javascript:

```js
function correct(nValue, nMin, nStep, nMax, nCorrectStep){ // correct(int, int, int, int, int): int
console.log("Input: "+nValue); // DEBUG
    if(nValue == nMin+Math.floor((nMax-nMin)/nStep)*nStep){ // pull up to max value that is a valid value after html attributes but not a correct value after the else block below
        console.log("Output: "+nMax); // DEBUG
        return nMax;
    }
    else{
        console.log("Output: "+(nMin+Math.floor((nValue-nMin)/nCorrectStep)*nCorrectStep)); // DEBUG
        return nMin+Math.floor((nValue-nMin)/nCorrectStep)*nCorrectStep; // round down to next valid step by multiply nCorrectStep again after downward adjusted dividing with nCorrectStep
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="0" step="5" max="105" value="0" onchange="this.value = correct(parseInt(this.value), parseInt(this.min), parseInt(this.step), parseInt(this.max), 10);"/>
```